# Main section doesnt take up vertical space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a new design, were I have a header, a side menu, and a footer within the main section.

[image: Layout design example]

I'm trying to make the main section fill the remaining of the space as a minimum height, pushing the footer to the bottom of the page.

I want the main section to take up the remaining space if needed, but everything should scroll when the main section is larger then the view height, so no sticky headers or footers.

is this something that can be done within Bootstrap 5? I see these types of designs often mentioned when talking about CSS grid, but I'm wondering if it's possible without it.

I've tried different setups using bootstrap flex utilities, but my Bootstrap/CSS knowledge only goes so far.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

<div class="h-100 container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row bg-warning">
    <div class="col-12 py-4 header">header</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row no-gutter flex-grow">
    <div class="col-1 bg-primary">
      <div class="sidebar-item">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-11 px-0">
      <div class="main bg-success flex-grow">
        Main
      </div>
      
      <div class="bg-danger py-3">
        Main Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100vh;` on `.main` ?

Comment: @ProblemChild, have you? If you had, you'd see that 100vh is too much. Rather than posting guesses in comments, copy the snippet down and attempt your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the containing column a flex container, then you can apply grow to the row inside.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

<div class="h-100 container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row bg-warning">
    <div class="col-12 py-4 header">header</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row no-gutter flex-grow">
    <div class="col-1 bg-primary">
      <div class="sidebar-item">Sidebar</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-11 d-flex flex-column px-0">
      <div class="main bg-success flex-grow-1">
        Main
      </div>

      <div class="bg-danger py-3">
        Main Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```